# Calling a partial view from AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is my ajax call to a partial view once I have done some processing:

```
function success(data) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/Orders/DraftOrderDetailsLineItems",
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'html',
    data: { "customerId": data.CustomerId },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data != "") {
            $('#draftOrderItems').html(data);
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error("[Error in Ajax Request, Get Line Items] Code:" + jqXHR.status + " Error:" + errorThrown + " \nText Status:" + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```

}

On my view I have the following:

```
  <tbody id="draftOrderItems">
     @Html.Partial("_draftOrderDetails", Model.Order);
  </tbody>
```

When I am stepping through the code, the draftorder partial view is called and I can see the data filling in the view.  However, the page it is hosted on is not "refreshing" the view to show the partial view.

Partial View:

```
 @using System.Linq
@model xxxxxx

@foreach (var lineItem in Model.LineItems)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "ImageBlocks", new { imageID = lineItem.Product.SelfOrDefault().Image.SelfOrDefault().ImageId, Width = 75 })" alt="Thumbnail" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <span title="@(lineItem.Description ?? "")">@(lineItem.Product.ReceiptName ?? "")</span><br />
            <span>@lineItem.Product.SKU</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>@lineItem.Product.InventorySummary</span><br />
        </td>
        <td>@lineItem.Quantity</td>
        @if (lineItem.Discount != null ? lineItem.Discount.DiscountCategory != DiscountCategory.ORDER : true)
        {
            <td>
                @lineItem.AdjustedUnitPrice.Value.ToString("C")
                <br />(Save @(lineItem.DiscountDisplayValue))
            </td>
            <td>@lineItem.AdjustedTotalLinePrice.Value.ToString("C")</td>
        }
        else
        {
            <td>@lineItem.BaseUnitPrice.Value.ToString("C")</td>
            <td>@lineItem.TotalLineBaseValue.ToString("C")</td>
        }
    </tr>
}
```

So I know that the ajax is called, the partial view is rendered, but for some reason it is not displaying on the hosting view.  Can anyone see something I am missing?

Here is the controller code:

```
 public ActionResult DraftOrderDetailsLineItems (Guid customerId)
    {
        //lookup cart based on customer ID
        var draftOrder = new ComApiCart(customerId,LoggedInUserID);

        return PartialView("_draftOrderDetails",draftOrder.OrderDetails);
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you debug into the javascript and see what exactly is returning in `data`?  Or check the networks tab and see what the response was.

Comment: Nevermind, you are missing a #.  `$('draftOrderItems')` should be `$('#draftOrderItems')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing the # in the jQuery selector.

```
$('draftOrderItems').html(data);
```

should be

```
$('#draftOrderItems').html(data);
```

Comment: I saw that and put in the # on an edit.  Still not working

Comment: In the console, under the networks tab, do you see the response?

Comment: Make sure `Model.LineItems` is not empty as well.  If it is then you'll end up skipping the loop in the partial.  Everything looks fine, assuming you are getting data etc.  Put a debugger stop inside the loop in the partial, put a debugger stop in the js in the response.  That should shed some light.

Comment: After doing some more testing, it appears that there is a conflicting script that is being called after my script that does a page refresh which is wiping out the partialview.  I was able to see the partial view data in the debugger and it is correct, but it was during a debugging session that we found that it was calling the page again and wiping out the line item.  Thanks to everyone who pitched in.